# main.register как сделать email логином?

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет !

Есть компонент bitrix:main.register, который выводит форму регистрации:

```
http://joxi.ru/Dr8DLwLtz8V39r
```

Поле ФИО записывается в Логин, а EMAIL соответственно в EMAIL

```
http://joxi.ru/Rmznl6lcRe6zRm
```

Помогите сделать так, что бы ФИО записывалось в ИМЯ, а EMAIL в логин и в EMAIL

```
http://joxi.ru/zANbl1lC69b7eA
```

Comment: Можно решать это перепроверив и почитав док про параметры вызова компонента, и правкой шаблона компонента регистрации (предварительно скопировав в своё пространство /local/). должно всё получиться, но на самый крайний случай есть событие перед добавлением пользователя, где можно перетасовать данные/поля как угодно (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onbeforeuseradd.php).